# Confusing Uncaught Reference Error for global JS variable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

Before I'm attempting to namespace my code, and have 2 coffeescript files in a rails project that generate this:

```
(function(){
  window.Investments = {};
}).call(this);
```

Then My backbone collection:

```
(function(){
  Investments.InfrastructureCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
}).call(this);
```

The console in chrome throws a `Uncaught ReferenceError: Investments is not defined` where I set up my InfrastructureCollection on page load, but everything seems to execute fine and things load up as they should. I can even create new instances of the collection and add models in the console without having to set anything up. What's going on here in the console to throw the error?

Comment: You should try `(function(investments) { /* get investments in this scope*/... }).call(window.Investments); ` Passing in `this` in the call refers to the window object.

Comment: What order do those two lines of code run in?  It sounds like they may be backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to check is to see if this works:

```
var Investments = {};
Investments.InfrastructureCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
```

without all the other stuff around it.  And, then if that doesn't work, then see if this works:

```
window.Investments = {};
window.Investments.InfrastructureCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
```

These will verify that your creation of the `.Investments` object is in place or whether there was some problem with that.

Then, lastly I see no reason why you would be doing all this inside of two separate instances of this:

```
(function(){

}).call(this);
```

The immediately executing function is normally used to create a temporary scope for privacy or for local variables, but you have none of those so it is not needed for that reason.  Secondly, why the `.call(this)`.  Again, that's an extra amount of code that simply isn't being used in any way.  If you want `this` to stay what it is, then just get rid of the immediately executed function block in the first place.

If you still aren't able to figure this out, then please try to create a simple reproducible example in a jsFiddle so we can see more exactly what is happening.

Comment: I'm doing these in coffeescript files, and I have a different file for each model, view, collection and then a file that loads before that set's up the namespace and some other options (_template settings, other options, etc.). In development mode, rails loads up each page as a separate resource to make it easier to work on and find errors, hence the separate instances of this.

Comment: @thatmiddleway - But, you're not using `this` within the immediately executed function so the `.call(this)` isn't needed or used.  Did you try either of the things I recommended?

Comment: window.Investments.InfrastructureCollection did the trick, but I'm not sure why it needed it and none of the models or views did.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what context you are calling these in (i.e. what `this` is referring to in your call) but perhaps you should change to:

```
(function(context){
  context.Investments = {};
}).call(window);
```

Also not sure why you can't just declare investments prior to accessing InfrastructureCollection

```
Investments = {};
Investments.InfrastructureCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
```

Comment: I have Investments as a namespace for the models and views as well (Investments.InfrastructureView, Investments.InfrastructureModel, etc.), and each is in a different file.

Comment: It does not matter what `this` refers to. There is no reference to `this` within the function.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you keep your order of self invoking functions in order like this, you'll be OK. The declaration of namespace obviously has to come first before the `Collection, Model, etc.`.

```
/**Initialize namespace */
(function(){
    window.Investments = {};
}).call(this);

/** Collection */
(function(){
    Investments.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
}).call(this);

/** Model */
(function(){
    Investments.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({});
}).call(this);
```

**OR** just invoke the anonymous function as is and inject the `Investments` object to make sure that it is indeed in scope (you have to additional checks if the specific object exists).

```
/**Initialize namespace */
(function(){
    window.Investments = {};
})();

/** Collection */
(function(inv){
    inv.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
})(window.Investments || {});

/** Model */
(function(inv){
    inv.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({});
})(window.Investments || {});
```

Another option that you can take if you're worried about the `order` or your modules is to use an [AMD](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/AsynchronousDefinition) framework like [Require JS](http://requirejs.org/) so you don't have to worry about it and you can configure dependencies and it will just run.